# Flatten a N-Dimensional Array into a 1D Array in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

Goal: Transform a array that has N number of nested lists, into a 1D array using Python3.

Example Array: `ND_array = [1, [2, 3], [4, [5, 6]], 7, [8, 9, [10, 11, 12, [13, [14, 15, 16], 17], 18], 19, 20], 21]` 
Transform the example array into the following result: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]`

A optimal solution that is not restricted on the number of dimensional the original array possess.

Comment: Please show what have you tried?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A simple and easy solution that works on any N-Dimensional array in python would be to utilize recursion.

```
oneD_array = []

def transform_array(arr):
    for x in arr:
        if type(x) == list:
            transform_array(x)
        else:
            oneD_array.append(x)
    return oneD_array
```

ND_array = [1, [2, 3], [4, [5, 6]], 7, [8, 9, [10, 11, 12, [13, [14, 15, 16], 17], 18], 19, 20], 21]

```
print(transform_array(ND_array))

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
```

Version 2.0 : Same output as above

```
def transform_array(arr, oneD_array):
    for x in arr:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            transform_array(x, oneD_array)
        else:
            oneD_array.append(x)
    return oneD_array
```

Comment: This is amazing and works perfectly! No other solution on StackOverFlow is this simple, and can be used on any N-Dimensional arrays.

Comment: @user22878443 What have you searched for? There are quite literally hundreds of duplicates and pretty much all the answers are as simple as this one. Plus: this one is quite terrible actually! What use is a function if you can only use it once because of the clumsy use of a global variable. Also, don't use `type(...) == ...` to check types. Use `isinstance`!

Comment: Many of the other articles are using imported packages to solve the problem and some do not work with heavy dimensional arrays from what I have found. This solution provides a solid baseline to build off of. I do not believe that it is a terrible solution as they answered the question with a baseline recursion solution. You can always build off of the example code given to not include the use of a global variable; as I have done in my code. May not be the most optimal solution, but provided a solid foundation. I do agree replacing the first if statement with "if isinstance(x, list):" is better

Comment: Correct, I intended the solution to be modified into your current code using no new packages. You can add a second parameter to the transform_array function and keep returning the list in the recursion call after the if-statement. When you initially call the function just have a empty list as the second parameter.